# Why does my for loop not go up to the first index in this W shaped nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I am stuck with reordering letter using arrays with a W shape. My code didn’t go up to level 0, but rather went down again.

Here is my code:

```
const row = totalLevel =>{
    let array = []
    for(let i =0;i<totalLevel;i++){
        array.push([])
    }
    return array
  }
  const inside = (str,rows) =>{
    let rowLevel = row(rows)
    // console.log(rowLevel)
    let level = 0
    for(let i =0;i<str.length;i++){
      rowLevel[level].push(str[i])
      if(level<rows-1){
        level++
      }
      else if(level === rows-1){
        level--
      }

    }
    console.log(rowLevel)
    let result =''
    for(let i =0;i<rowLevel.length;i++){
      result+= `Level ${i}: ${rowLevel[i]} \n`
    }
  return result
}
Driver code:
console.log(inside('DARWINFOX', 3))

//   Illustration : 
// D             I              X
//     A    W     N     O
//         R         F

//   expected result : DIXAWNORF
//   Final result will be: 
//   Level 1 : D, I, X
//   Level 2 : A, W, N, O
//   Level 3 : R, F
```

Comment: Do you have plans for this to work outside of just sending it to the console?

Comment: just sending it to console, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(level < rows - 1)` will be true again as soon as you leave level 2. You want to change the direction only if your level reaches the upper or lower bound, depending on the direction.

Change your `inside` function’s `for` loop part to this:

```
const inside = (str, rows) => {
  let rowLevel = row(rows),
    level = 0,
    direction = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    rowLevel[level].push(str[i]);

    if (level <= 0 && direction < 0 || level >= rows - 1 && direction > 0) {
      // When level reaches boundary, in a given direction
      direction = -direction; // Flip direction
    }

    level += direction; // Add current direction to level
  }

  // … let result, etc., etc.
}
```